# verificar elementos consecutivos iguales en string

Tags: javascript, string

Que tal tengo esta **funcion** que recibe un **string** y devuelve cuantos **consecutivos** hay en el **string**, tendria que recorrer los elementos del string y verificar si el elemento es igual al siguiente y si es sumar 1 al counter.

```
function consecutivosSimilares(str) {
        let counter = 0;
        let caracter = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        caracter = str.charAt(i);
        if(caracter == str.charAt(i))
        counter += counter
        return counter
}

consecutivosSimilares(“AAAA”) debe retornar 3
consecutivosSimilares(“BBBBB”) debe retornar 4
consecutivosSimilares(“ABABABAB”) debe retornar 0
consecutivosSimilares(“BABABA”) debe retornar 0
consecutivosSimilares(“AAABBB”) debe retornar 4
```

```
    *alguna idea si mi codigo va bien...*
```

Comment: deberías mostrar en la pregunta si tienes algún tipo de error cuando la ejecutas, así seria más fácil intentar ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte de los problemas de indentación que presenta tu código, tengo algunas observaciones:

- Nunca aumentas el `counter`, por lo que siempre será 0.
- Siempre comparas el caracter contra sí mismo, por lo que asumiendo que tu indentación fuera correcta, siempre entrarías en ese if.

Para poder hacer la validación podrías empezar desde el elemento 1, y de ahí comparar contra el elemento anterior. En caso de que sean iguales, aumentas el contador en 1.

```js
function consecutivosSimilares(str) {
  let counter = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    caracter = str.charAt(i);
    if (caracter === str.charAt(i - 1)) {
      counter += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log(counter);
  return counter
}

consecutivosSimilares('AAAA') // debe retornar 3
consecutivosSimilares('BBBBB') // debe retornar 4
consecutivosSimilares('ABABABAB') // debe retornar 0
consecutivosSimilares('BABABA') // debe retornar 0
consecutivosSimilares('AAABBB') // debe retornar 4
```

Claro, el ejemplo es simple pero también tendrías que validar la longitud de la cadena para evitar problemas con el for.

Con la misma lógica podrías usar el método [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para ahorrar un par de líneas de código, básicamente ocurre lo mismo que cuando usas un for y un contador.

```js
function consecutivosSimilares(str) {
  return Array.from(str)
    .reduce((acc, cur, i) => cur === str[i - 1] ? acc + 1 : acc, 0);
}

console.log(consecutivosSimilares('AAAA')); // debe retornar 3
console.log(consecutivosSimilares('BBBBB')); // debe retornar 4
console.log(consecutivosSimilares('ABABABAB')); // debe retornar 0
console.log(consecutivosSimilares('BABABA')); // debe retornar 0
console.log(consecutivosSimilares('AAABBB')); // debe retornar 4
```

Comment: ya entendí mejor en donde estaba atorado, gracias por la ayuda me sirvió para resolver la duda.